# assets not loading angular 2

Tags: angular, webpack

I am unable to load any photo from assets that I added after npm update. I get response 404 not found. All photos that I added to assets before update are still accessible. following is sc of network tab.

[image]

Two resoucres down arrow and enterprise logo are also from same asset folder and are asscssible but arrow-down0512 is not.
Images accessible are those I added to assets before update and one with 404 is added after update.

**Update**

Follwing is my html tag for image.

```
<div class="uparrow">
  <img src="/assets/images/arrow-down-01-512.png">
</div>
<div class="downarrow">
  <img src="/assets/images/downarrow.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: try removing `/` eg: `src="assets/images/arrow-down-01-512.png"`

Comment: check your `angular-cli.json` where `"assets": ["assets"]` is listed?

Comment: did you re-run ng serve or ng build after you added the assets? The assets are only copied to the appropriate directory once you run these commands. It is possible your dist directory has the old copy of assets (before you added the arrow-down-01-512.png)

Comment: Can you try? <img class="downarrow" src="../../assets/downarrow.png">

Comment: @Dhyey removing / does not work .same response.

Comment: @Hareesh this is my assets array in angular-cli.json `"assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ], `

Comment: @LLai i ran ng serve again but no luck. same response 404 not found.  any other suggestion?

Comment: @H.Hakvoort`src="../../assets/downarrow.png"` also does not work.

Comment: what  packages are updated?

Comment: @Hareesh assets get updated but that arrow-down-01-512.png is still not there

Comment: Rename it and try

Comment: same response @Hareesh. But why type of that image is text/plain while type of other images being loaded is png.any guesses why is that ?